# Google +1 button is shared across multiple subpages, but it shouldn't

Tags: javascript, redirect, google-plus, google-plus-one

we have problem that we are unable to solve and we really need help with it. We have page with a lot of subpages. It works like a blog. Each page has one video and some context. Each page also has Google +1 button. That button should give +1 to current subpage.

We have 75 subpages (so as articles) and most of them works fine with Google +1 button. But about 13 of them are broken right now and count is shared across them and main domain. We don't know when it happens.

We use exactly this code:

```
<div class="g-plusone" data-size="tall"></div>
<script type="text/javascript">
    window.___gcfg = {lang: 'cs'};
    (function() {
        var po = document.createElement('script'); po.type = 'text/javascript'; po.async = true;
        po.src = 'https://apis.google.com/js/plusone.js';
        var s = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0]; s.parentNode.insertBefore(po, s);
    })();
</script>
```

I tried to debug it. So first as you can see, we don't use data-href attribute and also we dont use The page's `<link rel="canonical" ... />` tag as it is suggested there: https://developers.google.com/+/web/+1button/#target-url

So first I debuged `document.location.href` and the value is correct. Then I used data-href attribute to force url. It didn't help. So I inspected iframe generated with google code and even values in iframe are correct. Button should point correct url. Even when you click button, it writes correct title, but somehow it is connected with more pages.

We think that problem could be connected with google crawling. Becouse our mainpage is redirected on last article. But we don't know that for sure.

There are 2 links of pages that shares same count, so they doesn't work correct:

- http://www.jaknainternet.cz/page/1750/e-mail/
- http://www.jaknainternet.cz/page/1751/socialni-site/

And the article where the button is correct:

- http://www.jaknainternet.cz/page/1745/reklama-na-internetu/

**EDIT 1:**

Some links has correct count right now, but others not. So it seems that problem is really with some google bot that caches our pages...

Actual links that **doesn't have correct G+ values** (basicaly value>50 isn't correct):

- http://www.jaknainternet.cz/page/1759/jak-na-prenos-velkych-souboru/
- http://www.jaknainternet.cz/page/1751/socialni-site/
- http://www.jaknainternet.cz/page/1739/sdileni-referenci-na-internetu/

Comment: does this issue still exist? all three URLs show me different counts (2 for the first, 54 for the second and 3 for the last one)

Comment: It does, 54 is not correct. I will edit my question.

Comment: The value 54 is correct as far as google is concerned. It probably has to do with the fact that your main page got redirected to the last article, messing with that article's counter at the time it got `+1`ed by users. Setting data-href attribute in the google plus div will prevent this from happening again, but I don't believe there is a way to reset the current counters. Sorry, perhaps somebody else will know better. Note that the google bot has absolutely no relationship with the +1 counters.

Comment: @foibs Im still not very sure about google bot. There was an article, that has +54 for sure. But now, it has correct count +2. So something has to happen... and we didnt do anything. So I think that something has to realize that there are 2 different pages, not one... so I think, it has to be google bot.

Answer (score -1):

Setting the +1 target URL

The URL that is +1'd is determined in the following order:

1. The button's href attribute
   This attribute explicitly defines the +1 target URL.
2. The page's  tag
   If the +1 button's href attribute is not provided, Google uses the page's canonical URL. For more information on defining the canonical URL for a page, see this help article.
3. The URL provided by document.location.href , which is not recommended.
   If none of these items are present, Google uses the URL of the page as found in the DOM. Because this URL might contain session IDs, anchors, or other parameters that are not actually part of the canonical URL, we highly recommend either setting the href attribute for the +1 button or adding a  tag to your page.

Do I need to use the href attribute?
The href attribute is not required. See +1 target URL for more information https://developers.google.com/+/web/+1button/?hl=pt-br#target-url

Do all my pages need to have a rel="canonical" tag?
No, though we recommend it. If the href attribute isn't set, Google will next look for the rel="canonical" tag on the page. If that isn't found, Google will use the document.location.href. This final value can sometimes be misleading because of state variables often kept in the URL. So, using a rel="canonical" tag can help you specify the exact URL you want +1'd.

Comment: Extracting text from developers.google.com isn't the answer to my question.